# Clearing datagridview with datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

My application has an datagridview that displays data via mysql connector, i want to clear or refresh the datagrid, but can't figure out how.

I tried

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
```

but it won't clear the data source.

This is my code

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

Boolean DataLoaded = false;
    string SQL = null;

    MySqlConnection MysqlConn;
    MySqlCommand WerkDataCommand = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlDataAdapter WerkDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable WerkData = new DataTable();

private void gegevensOphalenBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MysqlConn = new MySqlConnection();

        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=myserver;" + "user id=user;" + "password=***;" + "database=database";

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM werkverslagen";


        try
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
            MysqlConn.Open();

            WerkDataCommand.Connection = MysqlConn;
            WerkDataCommand.CommandText = SQL; 

            WerkDataAdapter.SelectCommand = WerkDataCommand;
            WerkDataAdapter.Fill(WerkData);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = WerkData;
        }
        catch (MySqlException myerror)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database gives the following error: " + myerror.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            MysqlConn.Close();
            MysqlConn.Dispose();
            button4.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

It will still keep the datasource and adds the same rows to the grid.

Comment: Where did you define the "WerkData"? What data type is it?

Comment: Added the WerkData Definition.

Comment: You can cheat a bit. When you want to clear the dataGridView, you can use the `WerkData.Clear()` method, and then 
`dataGridView2.DataSource = WerkData`
That way the dataGridView will clear all the data, but the headers will remain. After that, you can use the 
`dataGridView.DataSource = null` to clear the displayed headers.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to do:

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

Comment: Same error, cannon clear this list at dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
. after getting the information a second time. To be clear, the adapter will get the columns and put it in the datagridview, they aren't created in the collection. so datagridview2.rows.clear won't do anything.